# VSCode with unity c# autocomplete problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am on Windows 10(64-bit), VSCode 1.47.3, unity 2019.4.4f1 and .NET core 3.1.

I am trying to edit unity scripts but i can't find any autocomplete for the unity functions, variables and classes.

[Also I have installed the following vscode plugins:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cusgM.jpg)

And I have vscode as the default editor in unity.

--Help please.--

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem finally i found out I had installed mono and gtk in windows and added bin folder to system variable. Then reopening vscode worked at the first time it will take about 1 minute in my case.
Download mono from here: [click-here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)

Comment: and also download ms-dotnettools.csharp  extension for vscode from extension